# "Don't let him to mislead you" vs "Don't let him mislead you"

Tags: grammaticality

I have some questions about these statements:

> Don't let him to mislead you
>
> Don't let him mislead you

1. Are both of the sentences correct?
2. If both are interchangeable, which one sounds more natural to a
   native speaker?
3. Is there a rule or structure that governs the second example - as that sentence does not have the full infinitive?

Other examples could be:

```
"Don't let the devil deceive you."
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Allow (to) + infinitive, substantive, verb+ -ing.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing) I'm sure the main reason learners have trouble here is simply because [*syntactically, **let** doesn't work exactly the same as **allow.***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/11197/126)

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is incorrect. The second statement Is perfect!

“let him to” is never used in UK English or any other English I know.