# Which one is more common: "allow to reduce" or "allow reducing"?

Tags: verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Activation allows (to reduce/ reducing) the temperature of the process.

I found that "reducing" can be used after "allow". Moreover, we can write "to reduce" after "allow", too. But which one is more common?

Comment: Could you please provide a whole sentence where you intend using this structure?

Comment: Activation allows (to reduce/ reducing) the temperature of the process.

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing?rq=1) answer or question?

Answer (score 3):

I am making this a community wiki since this answer is totally based upon the conclusions of another answer, which is [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer given by @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica on a similar (almost same) question.

Answering your question in simple words, these are the possible and correct variations:

> Activation allows **us to reduce** the temperature of the process.
>
> Activation allows **reducing** the temperature of the process.
>
> Activation allows **reduction of** the temperature of the process.

For detailed explanation you can refer to the post I have linked or the post which is linked therein pointing to an answer on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

The option *"allows to reduce"* needs an object in between to complete the meaning, so it will be *"allows us to reduce."*

The combination *"allow + -ing"* is both *pragmatically* and *idiomatically* valid in your sentence in that I think it's most similar to the verbs "*enables/provides/includes* an [additional] option".

*Both* are common - it's a matter of style and interpretation.

Comment: _Activation be allowed to reduce the temperature of the process._ This is absolutely wrong. What sense does that even make? Do rewrite your sentence in case I am understanding it wrong. Also ping me so that I can retract my downvote.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh I upvoted your answer. I see why you downvoted mine. I wrote it that way because I don't expect the same subject. In dictionaries, you will find infinitives, not subject-agreement specified verbs.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it is hard to see how you have ended up trying to use the construction you are attempting to use.

“Activation allows” is an ugly way to start the sentence and leads you into difficulties.

Would “Activation reduces the temperature” meet the needs of the message being communicated?