# usage of demonstrative pronouns

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-pronouns

I am writing an article. I have two sentences. The first sentence introduces a thesis. In the second sentence there is a reference to it. Should I use the relative pronoun "this" or "that" in the second sentence.

Here are my sentences (A and B):

> A: It turns out, however, that waveguides having step-index refractive index profile are more favorable because they allow to obtain higher sensitivities.

> B:
> The theoretical prove to this thesis was presented in Ref. [18].

I would use "this thesis". However, I read many artices and it seems that usage of "that thesis" is more common.

Comment: "this" is perfectly acceptable. I can however see three other mistakes. It might be worth your while employing a proof-reader to check the whole article.

Comment: I've the "subjectless" construction as in OP's *because they **allow to** obtain [something]* quite often in recent years. Almost always from non-native speakers though, so I think it still counts as "non-idiomatic" for mainstream Anglophones. See [*Allow (to) + infinitive, substantive, verb+ -ing*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing/11197) as asked here previously.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments :) . Maybe the use of "allow for" is better.