# usage of the verb "enable"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Which one of the following sentences does use "enable" grammatically correct?

> 1. Studying different subjects **enables students to broaden** their horizons.
> 2. Studying different subjects **enables to students to broaden** their horizons.

According to dictionaries, 1 must be correct but there are so many sentences on the Internet and even in native American conversations that 2 is used.

For example:

1. [Gift of $2m enables to US Squash to appoint Head National Coach](https://squashmad.com/breaking-news/gift-of-2m-enables-to-us-squash-to-appoint-head-national-coach/)
2. [Illini PRA enables to students to explore public relations field](https://dailyillini.com/features/2010/10/13/illini-pra-enables-to-students-to-explore-public-relations-field-2/)

Comment: There are a lot of native English speakers out there who don't use English very well.

Comment: It looks like this is a more common error than I thought - here is another example: *The website MedicalEducation.nl **enables to students** to access online medical Computer Based Training material any time and any place.* https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4262724

Comment: @ColleenV That is a translation or written by Dutch people according to the list of authors, and it was published in Slovenia. There were probably no English editors on hand and it is a mistake in English. And simply not the **type of mistake** a native English speaker would make....

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I agree. It would be a typo or cut and paste error if done by someone fluent. I just didn't realize it was as common a mistake among non-native speakers as it appears to be.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, and it is a typical red-flag mistake. This is the kind of thing I deal with on a daily basis. Correcting translations or writing done by non-English speakers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow (to) + infinitive, substantive, verb+ -ing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing) Essentially, the somewhat "fluid" syntax of ***to allow*** is being extended to semantically similar verbs such as ***to enable, to permit***. So far, it's mainly non-native speakers who take the syntax beyond ***to allow***, but I'm sure that will change soon enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think "enable" can take a gerund complement when it's being used in the sense of "make possible". *A passport enables visiting other countries.* seems like it should use object/infinitive *A passport enables someone to visit other countries.* *A passport enables foreign travel.* seems OKish although I don't like that wording. I feel like it should be "allow" not "enable". Maybe I just picked a bad example. Regardless, I'm not sure if that question is a good duplicate on ELL because it's not explicit how "allow" and "enable" are related.

Comment: allow is also a causative verb.

Answer (score 3):

Sentences with "enable to NOUN to VERB" are not grammatical in English.

The verb [enable](https://web.archive.org/web/20220812070513/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enable) is [transitive](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/what-are-the-types-of-verbs/), and in the sense of "make possible" it takes both an object and an infinitive.

In the sentence:

> Studying different subjects **enables students to broaden** their horizons.

the object is "students" and the infinitive is "to broaden".

In the sentence:

> Studying different subjects **enables <sup>∗</sup>to students to broaden** their horizons.

the ["to" as a preposition](https://web.archive.org/web/20220203221609/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/to) *identifying the person or thing affected* is unnecessary, because "enable" is transitive. We usually only need "to" as a preposition when the verb is intransitive and we want to express who or what the verb is affecting. For example:

> The teacher spoke to the students.

not

> The teacher spoke <sup>∗</sup>the students.

With an intransitive verb, we don't *have* to add the infinitive; "The teacher spoke." is grammatical but "The teacher threw." is not<sup>1</sup> because throw is transitive and requires an object.

We can't form an infinitive with a noun like "students" and even if we could, we wouldn't have an [object](https://web.archive.org/web/20220627045825/https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/object) (*A noun or noun phrase governed by an active transitive verb or by a preposition.*) which the transitive verb "enable" requires.

---

<sup>1.</sup>  Well, usually. In some contexts the object might be missing because it is inferred from the context. For example,

*From the corner of her eye, the pitcher saw a runner trying to steal a base. She spun and threw. “Out!” yelled the
umpire.*

Comment: @Lambie there was one thing I wasn't sure about though that maybe you can help with... Is there a word for verbs that take both an object and an infinitive? "enable" doesn't seem to be "ditransitive" like "sell" or "give" and I wasn't able to figure out what to call it.

Comment: It falls under the list of causative verbs, like help, get, make, let, assist, have....all of which take a pronoun (person) or thing (noun) as an object.

Answer (score 2):

> 1- Studying different subjects **enables students to broaden** their horizons.

> 2- Studying different subjects **enables to students to broaden** their horizons.

Example1 is fine, but example 2 is not.

One must be discerning and choose reliable sources for learning materials.

As for your suspicion that the phrase
'enables to students to broaden' is used in native American conversations, I believe there could be a mistake in listening; the speaker may actually be saying 'enables *the* students to broaden'.

Comment: To be honest, the original sentence that I head is
"... enables to them to broaden their horizons". "them" refers to students.