# Can "allow to" be used without a subject?

Tags: grammar

I'm proofreading English translations of Spanish scientific articles for journals. The translations are very good, but I keep coming across "allow to" without a subject.  This sounds odd to me.

The text says something like "This new method allows to streamline the process". Shouldn't it be something like "allows us to", or "allows researchers to"? I've come across this several times and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: "us" is the object of allows, and only implicitly the subject of "streamline".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow (to) + infinitive, substantive, verb+ -ing.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/allow-to-infinitive-substantive-verb-ing) There must be something about the verb ***to allow*** that particularly encourages non-native speakers to think allow + to + infinitive *(It allows to do something)* is valid. It turns up so often among nns that eventually even the natives will end up shrugging their shoulders and accepting it.

Comment: "This new method allows *one* to streamline the process" is neutral tone.  It does not limit the process to only researchers.  (Engineers, for example, or technicians might want to implement the process.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you are right.  "It allows to streamline something" is incorrect.

You may rephrase with an object "It allows us to streamline...", or you can use a participle phrase:  "It allows streamlining of the process".

(The "rules" around infinitives and participles are complex and unsystematic - it's quite possible that Spanish uses an infinitive in this context that English requires a participle)

Comment: Thanks James, very clear and well explained. You're right, in Spanish you could use the infinitive after allow.

Comment: Ah. That comment explains why we see this "error" so often here.

Comment: @James: You missed the third possibility after ***allow*** - With a **noun phrase object** indicating what is allowed, as in *Some states do not allow abortion* and *This school allows the use of computers during exams*.

Comment: Yes... was wondering whether "streamlining" might actually be a noun,

Comment: @JamesK I think "streamlining" is a gerund in this context, since it both *is* and *can have* a direct object (if you were to get rid of the optional preposition "of" - "allows streamlining the process")

Comment: Adding to what James K says: "allows one" can be useful, or in some cases the variant "allowed the author".

Answer (score 3):

The issue is one of "[valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics))". Generally we do not use "allow" with an infinitive unless it also has a direct object. You suggested two direct objects, either of which would be fine:

> This new method allows **us** to streamline the process.
> This new method allows **researchers** to streamline the process.

By the way, I think that you confused "subject" and "object". In this sentence, "allows" does, indeed, have a subject: "this new method".

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I thought. Yes, I definitely confused object and subject.